# fullcalendar access to php in different domain

Tags: php, json, events, dns, fullcalendar

I display the events from a database but in localhost, but how can I access the php file from a different domain?

Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'title',
                        right: 'prev,next today',
                        //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    //defaultDate: '2015-04-12',
                    lang: currentLangCode,
                    buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
                    weekNumbers: false,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    eventClick: function(event){
                         $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                         $('#modalBody').html(event.descripcio);
                         $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                     },
                    events: {
                            url: 'php/get-events.php',

                        error: function() {
                            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                        }}

                });
```

Comment: why you want to do so ?

Comment: I want to access from an application with FullCalendar to php files on a server who that shows me events to the application.

It works locally, but staying php files in the server is down. So that's my question about how to do that

Comment: it might be an server side issue. Check the server configuration and make the `php` files as executable.

Comment: Its not a problem of server and php files, the problem is how to access to php files from a external server but i know how to do this. The problem is about cross domain i know...